# Join by nearest date for the table with duplicate records in BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have `installs` table with installs that have the same `user_id` but different `install_date`.
I want to get all revenue records joined with nearest install record by `install_date` that is less then `revenue_date` because I need it's `source` field value for next processing.
That means that output rows count should be equal to revenue table records.
How can it be achieved in BigQuery?

Here is the data:

```
installs
install_date    user_id     source
--------------------------------
2020-01-10      user_a      source_I           
2020-01-15      user_a      source_II
2020-01-20      user_a      source_III
***info about another users***

revenue
revenue_date    user_id     revenue
--------------------------------------------
2020-01-11      user_a      10
2020-01-21      user_a      20
***info about another users***
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below solution

```
select any_value(r).*, 
    array_agg(
        (select as struct i.* except(user_id)) 
        order by install_date desc 
        limit 1
    )[offset(0)].*
from `project.dataset.revenue` r 
join `project.dataset.installs` i 
on i.user_id = r.user_id 
and install_date < revenue_date
group by format('%t', r)
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem but it is in SQL. How I can write this code into SQL? Regards

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `left join` for this:

```
select r.*, i.* except (user_id)
from revenue r left join
     (select i.*,
             lead(install_date) over (partition by user_id order by install_date) as next_install_date
      from installs i
     ) i
     on r.user_id = i.user_id and
        r.revenue_date >= i.install_date and
        (r.revenue_date < i.next_install_date or i.next_install_date is null);
```

I have had problems in the past with `left join`s and inequalities.  However, I think this will work now in BQ.